# Block access on Jira on port 8080

Tags: linux, apache, jira

I have a webserver CentOS 6.6. I run on this server a jira and a conflence aplications.
Jira link is http://jira.server.com:8080 and I vant to change on https and limit access on specify IPs.
I made an apache confirguration with proxy to conect via https and limit access on IPs on https://jira.server.com
But now I can acces the jira trough both links. How can I remove access to this link http://jira.server.com:8080?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be enough to change the binding address to `127.0.0.1` instead of the public ip or `0.0.0.0`.

Your `conf/server.xml` should look similar to this:

```
...
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080"
               address="127.0.0.1"
...
```

Comment: My connector tag looks like this:         <Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
                maxThreads="200" minSpareThreads="10"
                enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" debug="0" URIEncoding="UTF-8" /> I should add 'address="127.0.0.1"'?